# How to use the OES_texture_float extension? and create a texture as a floating point one for that?

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions

How to use the OES_texture_float extension? 
  and create a texture as a floating point one for that?

As webGL 1 extension lists:

```
  var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
  var linear =  gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, image);
```

How to make a float-point image as a texture input?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what behaviour's observed and what's desired? As per spec your code seems to be correct, however a bit strange (it's not very clear what is floating-point image in relation to HTMLCanvasElement and Image).

Answer (score 2):

First off you're not actually checking you got the extension

Your code should be something like

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
   alert("this machine or browser does not support OES_texture_float");
}   
var linear =  gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
if (!linear) {
   alert("this machine or browser does not support  OES_texture_float_linear");
}
```

Otherwise you didn't show enough code to see what else might be wrong. Have you read any [webgl tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org)? Where are you creating and binding the texture? What do your shaders look like? What kind of attributes are you using if any?

```js
function main() {
  var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
  if (!ext) {
    alert("this machine or browser does not support OES_texture_float");
    return;
  }   
  var linear = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
  if (!linear) {
    alert("this machine or browser does not support  OES_texture_float_linear");
    return;
  }

  var vs = `
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

  var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_tex;
void main () {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_tex, gl_PointCoord);
}
`;

  var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // let's use a canvas instead of an image. It should be the same
  var image = document.createElement("canvas"); 
  var ctx = image.getContext("2d");
  for (var i = 20; i > 0; --i) {
    ctx.fillStyle = i % 2 ? "red" : "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, i * 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  var tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, image);

  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Also it's not clear what you mean by "create a texture as a floating point one for that". If the features are supported then uploading the image it will get converted to floating point (which we see in the example above) but the input image is an 8bit image at best. If you really want floating point data you'll have to use binary data rather than an image.

```js
function main() {
  var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
  if (!ext) {
    alert("this machine or browser does not support OES_texture_float");
    return;
  }   
  var linear = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
  if (!linear) {
    alert("this machine or browser does not support  OES_texture_float_linear");
    return;
  }

  var vs = `
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

  var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_tex;
void main () {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_tex, gl_PointCoord) / vec4(32, 16, 32 + 16, 1);
}
`;

  var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // create floating point data directly
  var width = 32;
  var height = 16;
  var data = new Float32Array(width * height * 4);  // RGBA
  for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      var off = (y * width + x) * 4;
      data[off + 0] = x;
      data[off + 1] = y;
      data[off + 2] = x + y;
      data[off + 3] = 1;
    }
  }

  var tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, data);

  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. I  put my code on github:  https://github.com/bruce25796/OES_texture_float

Comment: ch05_github.zip was adopted from WebGL programming guide, using a 16x16 floating data with 4 channel float32 ( RGBA ) per pixel.     And I use Create32F_image. It was a visual studio 10 project , writing with CLR to generate a binary 16x16 floating data with 4 channel float32 ( RGBA ).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and I'm not going to debug your code. SO is not a "debug my code for my site". From the help: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce** it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*